# Razor vbhtml and <text> syntax

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, slickupload

I'm attempting to implement SlickUpload in VBHTML.

Using the C# Razor example I am getting a expression expected error.

```
.SelectorTemplate = 
    new Template(@<text> <a href="javascript:;">Add files</a></text>)
```

I think this is something to do with @, but I'm not sure. Is it possible to use the text syntax in vbhtml?

Comment: Show the full code block where you are using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add a lambda expression to the new template

```
    .SelectorTemplate = 
New Template(Sub() @<text> <a href="javascript:;">Add files</a></text> End Sub)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just my initial guess without seeing the full code block, but the parameter to the constructor of Template should be in double-quotes.

```
.SelectorTemplate = 
    new Template("<text> <a href=\"javascript:;\">Add files</a></text>")
```